# VBA Code interupts when I use workbooks.add(template)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a new workbook as a template of existing Excel file and faced with some difficulties. Everything is ok until this sting perfoms:

```
Set wkb = Workbooks.Add(Path & FileName)
'do next stuff
```

The new workbook creates, but the code interupts without any error message and VBE project window activates. The template is a macro-enable file and has userform. Any suggestions how to fix the issue will much appreciate.

update:

```
Path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
StrFile = Dir(Path & "*2014*")
Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
    NewFile = StrFile
    StrFile = Dir
    i = i + 1
Loop
Set wkb = Workbooks.Add(Path & NewFile)
wkb.SaveAs Filename:=Path & "0" & i + 1 & "=" & Format(Dateserial(2014,i +1,1), "mmmm") & "=2014.xlsm"
```

Comment: do you have 'On Error Resume Next' earlier in the sub? If yes, remove that code to see if you actually get an error? Secondly is the sub running all the way to the end? Add Msgbox("test") at the end of it to see if you get that message. if not, keep putting it up one line until you actually get that popup, that will tell us exactly which line is the problem.

Comment: @Nate I don't have 'On Error' statement. Put a `MsgBox wkb.Name` as you adviced and nothing happen. Also I removed `Displayalerts` statement and after that a dialog box arose : "do you want to reopen the file" etc. Click OK, the new file creates named as a template plus 1 at the and of the name, but msgbox isn't done.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Set wbk = Workbooks.Add
wbk.Name = Filename
wbk.Save...... (put filepath etc etc here).
```

Comment: Nate, thanks. Of course I considered this solution. But I want to get a success there using a template technique.

Comment: @Mormoch would you be able to post up a little of the code before and after your line of code. Furthermore, when you say it interupts without any error message, when the VBE project window activates, is any of the lines highlighted in yellow? if yes, which one?

Comment: I updated my question and put the code. No line is highlited.